# How to integrate "Available on" in Google Search?

Tags: google-search, netflix

When the user searches some movie or series he will able to see "Available on" section with streaming services. After that user can click on "Watch" action and navigate to the specific application.

How it can be achieved by other applications?

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Comment: I think it's not related to SEO. I'm interested in implementation from development side: which service is used for this purpose and etc.